# HTML input for Positive Whole Numbers Only (Type=number)

Tags: regex, html, validation

I can't find the right regex pattern for this, even though there are a lot of questions in this kind.

I dont want the user to be able to type or input

```
<td><input type="number" pattern=" 0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$" name="itemConsumption" /></td>
```

1. -1.0 (Negative values)
2. String Values and any character
3. 1.0 (Decimal Values)
4. No range Limit

I only want to accept positive whole numbers

SOLVED
no need for regex, I did not know this :D

```
<td><input type="number" pattern=" 0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$" name="itemConsumption" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"</td>
```

Comment: My two cents: `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="itemConsumption" />`. And please state what you *want to allow*. I think it will be easier.

Comment: I think you are missing one thing: `pattern` attribute only allows to control the data on *submit*. Not when user types.

Comment: Try [`<input type="text" name="itemConsumption" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" />`](http://jsfiddle.net/zhy7uway/).

Comment: @SCS: Please provide us some feedback, we are interested whether you solved the issue or not.

Comment: @stribizhev thank you the code <input type="text" name="itemConsumption" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" />. Perfectly Works

Comment: Doesn't working using Chrome on android

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To disallow any input but numeric, you may use

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" name="itemConsumption" />
                   ^------------....
```

```html
<form id="mfrm">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter number only: <input type="text" name="itemConsumption" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" /></td>
        <td><input type="Submit"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here, the `event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13` condition handles the case when DELETE, BACKSPACE or ENTER keys are pressed (important for Firefox, see [Mohit's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777184/html-input-for-positive-whole-numbers-only-type-number/32784911?noredirect=1#comment61101594_32784911) below and [datashaman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777184/html-input-for-positive-whole-numbers-only-type-number/32784911?noredirect=1#comment75541329_32784911) related to enabling the ENTER key).

The `event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57` means that only 0 (decimal code 48) and all other digits up to 9 (decimal code 57) will be returned.

Comment: in firefox backspace and delete key doesn't work if above code is added.

Comment: @MohitAdwani: Try [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/zhy7uway/2/): `onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"`

Comment: Works fine now. I think you should update your answer. Or maybe what you have posted, is what the user wants.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok, im going to that guy.. this doesnt work on IE8 :-)

Comment: Sorry, no idea who uses IE, and especially IE 8 :(, can't test.

Comment: You should also add character code 13 into that - otherwise you can't press Enter to submit the form when you are in that field.

Comment: This can be workaround(or abused) using copy pasted invalid values.

Answer (score 34):

You can use **type**, **min** and **oninput**

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
```

```html
<form>
<label>Input with positive numbers only</label><br/><br/>
<input type="number" min="0" step="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
</form>
```

Comment: max value isn't working?

Comment: @Harvey, Yes max value also work but this example is only for positive numbers.

Comment: This solution does work for this question (no range limit) but, as @Hrvoje alluded to, for anyone trying to set a max on the input, this will reset the input value to '' (blank) if the max is exceeded.

Answer (score 12):

I tried a lot of different solutions to achieve this, and I finally came up with this one, which does the job perfectly for us. It works for typing and for copy/paste, and I couldn't find any unwanted side-effects.

```
<form>
    <input
        type="number"
        min="0"
        step="1"
        onfocus="this.previousValue = this.value"
        onkeydown="this.previousValue = this.value"
        oninput="validity.valid || (value = this.previousValue)"
    />
</form>
```

It is like Nikhil Mahirrao's solution, but it will cause invalid keystrokes to be simply ignored without emptying the input.

Comment: This is perfect, works also with paste while @wiktor-stribiżew 's solution doesn't

Answer (score 8):

To allow only number values you can use as follows:

```
<td><input type="number" pattern="\d+" name="itemConsumption" /></td>
```

Comment: Why use anchors? The pattern attribute is anchored by default.

Comment: @stribizhev, as for me, it makes the expression more stringent

Comment: It will look like `/^(?:^\d+$)$/` for the internal engine. Rather clumsy :)

Comment: @stribizhev, thank for lesson, it is realy look clumsy. I use regexp for sql in the main, because I don't know about this

Comment: this line still accepts negative values -. (For future reference)

Comment: Are you sure? `\d` equals `[0-9]`

Answer (score 6):

If it comes to HTML5 then you might try [min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-min) attribute:

```
<input type="number" min="0">
```

Comment: You still can manually enter negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex pattern for whole numbers [0-9]* or \d*
[0-9] is range you can type 0 to 9 and * means not expecting any number or may you type infinite numbers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this jQuery Codepen snipet](https://codepen.io/artfulcat/pen/EzoxZM) will be helpful for someone.
It's for type="number" (not "text"):

```
<input class="js-input-absint" type="number" step="1" min="18"  max="150" name="age" value="50">
```

with [0-9] allowed inputs only. In the input will printed/pasted only numbers [0-9] with an min-max range (optional).

Some explanations: The code displays only numbers at the input stage, and does not reset the value to "" (empty) in case of inputting not valid number values like it does by default for type="number". And you can't use the attribute pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" for an input type="number".

```
var $inputAbsint = $('.js-input-absint');

if ($inputAbsint.length) {

  $(document).on('keypress', '.js-input-absint', function (event) {

    var allowed = /^[0-9]|Arrow(Left|Right)|Backspace|Home|End|Delete$/;
    return allowed.test(event.key);

  }).on('focusout paste', '.js-input-absint', function () {

    var $input = $(this);
    var defaultValue = this.defaultValue || $input.attr('min');
    // Important(!): Timeout for the updated value
    setTimeout(function () {
        var current = $input.val();
        var regexNumbers = new RegExp(/^[0-9]*$/, 'g');
        var isNumbersOnly = regexNumbers.test(current);
        // Clear wrong value (not numbers)
        if ((current === '' || !isNumbersOnly) && defaultValue.length) {
            $input.val(defaultValue);
            current = defaultValue;
        }
        // Min/Max
        var min = parseInt($input.attr('min'), 10);
        var max = parseInt($input.attr('max'), 10);
        var currentInt = parseInt(current, 10);
        if (!isNaN(min) && !isNaN(currentInt) && currentInt < min) {
            $input.val(min);
        }
        if (!isNaN(max) && !isNaN(currentInt) && currentInt > max) {
            $input.val(max);
        }
    }, 100);

  });

}
```

Comment: Please post the code in the answer in case the link expires

Answer (score 0):

You can't press ' - ' button on keyboard.

```
<!--HTML Code is below-->
<input type="text" name="value1" id="value1" class="form-control" required="required" onkeyup="keyCode(event)">

<!--JQuery Code is below-->
<script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $value1.on("keyup", function keyCode(event){
            var x = event.keyCode;
            if (x == 109 || x == 189) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert ("You can't enter minus value !");
            }
        });
      });
</script>
```

Keycode of '109' represent numeric side minus button of keyboard. Keycode of '189' represent minus button above of the character buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Nikhil Mahirrao answer is elegant and short!

I wanted something similar, however the field should not bounce back to an empty string, but in addition simply ignore any input that is not a number. Also, leading zeros should be filtered.

```
... oninput="filterNonNumbers(this)" ...

function filterNonNumbers(inputElement) {
    let valOriginal = inputElement.value;
    let valFiltered = valOriginal.split('').filter(c => c.charCodeAt(0) >= 48 && c.charCodeAt(0) <= 57 ? c : '').join('').replace(/^0+/, '');
    if (valOriginal !== valFiltered) {
        inputElement.value = valFiltered;
    }
}
```

Of course, it works just like Nikhil's code when typing directly as well as when pasting via the clipboard.

Perhaps someone has a similar, extended requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to throw out a solution to round it off upon input.

```
<input id="numinput" type="number" step=1 
oninput="validateWholeNumericInput('numinput', this.value)">

function validateWholeNumericInput(id, val) {

if(val<0){val=0;}
document.getElementById(id).value = Math.round(val);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mrliioadin/5sn2d07t/5/

Comment: The question specifies that the input should not allow the iser to input the negative numbers but your answer rounds off the non integer values and put it into the input value, which in my opinion is a bit out of context. Please read the question properly so that uour knowledge can actually help others. Thank you.

Comment: Fair point. Edited my answer to better address the question at hand. Cleaned the code too.