# Numeric only text box in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I want to make textbox numeric only in my Angular JS application.
Here is my code-
script.js

```
app.directive('numbersonly', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            elm.on('keydown', function (event) {
                if (event.which == 64 || event.which == 16) {
                    // to allow numbers  
                    return false;
                } else if (event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) {
                    // to allow numbers  
                    return true;
                } else if (event.which >= 96 && event.which <= 105) {
                    // to allow numpad number  
                    return true;
                } else if ([8, 13, 27, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(event.which) > -1) {
                    // to allow backspace, enter, escape, arrows  
                    return true;
                } else {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // to stop others  
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And on UI-

```
 <input type="text" id="txtEmpAge" data-ng-model="newemployee.Age" class="form-control" numbersonly required />
```

But the text box is accepting both numeric and character.

Comment: Use regex in your controller and look at ngPattern

Comment: maybe [How to allow only a number (digits and decimal point) to be typed in an input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036443/how-to-allow-only-a-number-digits-and-decimal-point-to-be-typed-in-an-input) helps you

Comment: If its one input only and you don't need it to be a directive you could use the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777184/html-input-for-positive-whole-numbers-only-type-number)

Answer (score 0):

If it is not necessary to use your own implementation, try [Angular's number type input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D).

Comment: well I changed input type to "number" instead of "text" and it is OK but its accepting decimal and that is not requirement.Any help?

Comment: Please check the pattern attribute of the tag. It allows you to specify a regex for the input.

Comment: <input type="number" id="txtEmpAge" ng-model="newemployee.Age" class="form-control" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' required />

Comment: I mean try something like this:
<input type="number" pattern="^\d+$">

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to provide example code to show what you mean.  In particular, don't rely on links to provide the necessary content; your answer should remain useful even if the link is unavailable at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type=number`

```
<input type="number" id="txtEmpAge" data-ng-model="newemployee.Age" class="form-control" required />
```

This will take only number values in the text box.

Comment: same thing that I did but its accepting decimal and that is not requirement.Any help?

Comment: Then you should use a directive to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, best way to achieve 
, it will also not allow user to copy paste strings to input

```html
<input type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet to make the input field to accept only characters between 0 to 9. This will eliminate the decimal pointer.

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumKey(event)"/>
```

use this function to trigger on key is pressed.

```
  function isNumKey(evt){
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight