# how to allow only numbers in textbox in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Hi am newbie to angular js?
How to allow numbers only in texbox once user enter decimal value or string showing error in angular js?

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
                                                        <label class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 pad-top5 pad-lft-no">Min <span class="error">*</span></label>
                                                        <input positive  type="number" class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 cls_input_inherit numberinput" min="0" ng-maxlength="3" id="age_min" name="age_min" ng-model="attributes.age_min"  required/>
                                                        <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.required" class="error">{{formValidation.required}}</label>                                                           
                                                        <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.positive &&  attributesForm2.age_min.$error.maxlength" class="error"> {{formValidation.monthMaxChar}} </label>
                                                        <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.positive && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.maxlength && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.min" class="error">{{formValidation.minMax}}</label>
                                                        <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.positive && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.maxlength && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.number" class="error">{{formValidation.errorNumber}}</label>
                                                        <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.positive" class="error">{{formValidation.minpositive}}</label>
                                                    </div>
```

Am try above code but it's not showing error when enter decimal value?How to solve it?

Comment: Find answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777184/html-input-for-positive-whole-numbers-only-type-number

Comment: Try using input type as `number` and `pattern="^[0-9]*$"` attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers

Comment: not working,<input positive  type="number" class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 cls_input_inherit numberinput" min="0" ng-maxlength="3" id="age_min" name="age_min" ng-model="attributes.age_min"   pattern="^\d+$" required/> am add pattern but not showing any error when add decimal value?how to show error message for pattern validate?change pattern too ^[0-9]*$ not showing any error still accept decimal value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/" in input field.

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
 <label class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 pad-top5 pad-lft-no">Min <span class="error">*</span></label>
                                                    <input positive  type="number" class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 cls_input_inherit numberinput" min="0" ng-maxlength="3" id="age_min" name="age_min" ng-model="attributes.age_min" ng-pattern="/^(\d)+$/" required/>
                                                    <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.required && attributesForm2.age_min.$touched && attributesForm2.age_min.$invalid"  class="error">{{formValidation.required}}</label>                                                           
                                                    <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.positive &&  attributesForm2.age_min.$error.maxlength" class="error"> {{formValidation.monthMaxChar}} </label>
                                                    <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.positive && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.maxlength && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.min" class="error">{{formValidation.minMax}}</label>
                                                    <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.positive && !attributesForm2.age_min.$error.maxlength && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.number" class="error">{{formValidation.errorNumber}}</label>
                                                    <label for="age_min" ng-show="submittab2 && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.positive" class="error">{{formValidation.minpositive}}</label>
                                                </div>
```

Comment: ya changed like above coding,not showing any error when given decimal value,also tired step="1"

Comment: you need to use this inside lable ng-show="submittab2 && attributesForm2.age_min.$error.required && attributesForm2.age_min.$touched && attributesForm2.age_min.$invalid"

Answer (score 0):

This is just alternative answer, try to use directive

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').directive('numOnly', numOnly);
  function numOnly(){
       var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                ngModel:'=ngModel'
            },
            link:link
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                var arr = String(newVal).split('');
                if (arr.length === 0) return;
                if (arr.length === 1 && (arr[0] === '-' || arr[0] === '.')) return;
                if (isNaN(newVal)) {
                    scope.ngModel = oldVal;
                }
            });
        }
  }

angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController);
  myController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function myController($scope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.txtNum = ''; // set default value as empty to avoid error in directive
    vm.txtNumTwo = ''; //set default value as empty to avoid error in directive

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.txtNum" num-only placeholder="Enter number" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.txtNumTwo" num-only placeholder="Enter number" />
   </div>
</div>
```