# Avoid enter dot in input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field which is of number type, when I enter the dot I am not getting the value. So what I am trying to achieve is the I don't want the user to enter dot on the input field

```js
function handleChange (value) {
 console.log(value)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onchange="handleChange(this.value)"/>
```

on each number entering I am getting the value, but when I type dot (.), I am not getting how can I block this when user type it

Comment: The code snippet you shared does exactly what you asked for . what is the problem ?

Comment: <input type="number" onkeyup="handleChange(this.value)"/>

Comment: Why dont you use some jquery to set the the value to '' when the user types a dot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML input for Positive Whole Numbers Only (Type=number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777184/html-input-for-positive-whole-numbers-only-type-number)

Comment: the type number does not exclude decimal numbers, thus avoiding the . might be fatal since typing in 2.4 is a valid input. If you try to put a dot after the 2.4 you will realize this does not work anymore, since a number does not have 2 dots. This is a completely intentional behaviour

Answer (score 1):

if you want to block '.' you can use this way,

```
function handleChange (value) {
console.log(value)
}

var inputBox = document.getElementById("inputBox");

var invalidChars = [
".",

];

inputBox.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (invalidChars.includes(e.key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
<input type="number" id="inputBox" onchange="handleChange(this.value)/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="num" type="number" min="1" step="1" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

referance from this url
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44379790/4316212

Answer (score 0):

Add This `oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')"`

```js
function handleChange (value) {
 console.log(value)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onchange="handleChange(this.value)" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) to use inline event handlers.

For more control you should check/use the [atributes of a number input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#additional_attributes).

If you want to *completely* control the input, use a readonly field and handle it using your own handler. Here's a snippet using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). It uses the `step` attribute from the number input field for adding/subtracting.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.dataset.numinput) {
    const inp = document.querySelector(`#num`)
    inp.value = ( +inp.value +  +(`${evt.target.dataset.numinput}${inp.step}`) )
      .toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="num" type="number" step="0.1" readonly/>
<button data-numinput="-"> - </button>
<button data-numinput="+"> + </button>
```