# Angular input field type number should allow only numbers from 0-9

Tags: html, angular, decimal

Having an input field where the user will enter the amount in it. i do want to restrict the users from entering decimal points.
Eg : if user tries to enter 121.2 , i should not allow him to place '.'(decimal point) character in the input box.

The below sample works on web but the same is not working on android mobile numberic keypad.

Sample-1

<input (keydown)="if(event.key==='.'){event.preventDefault();}" type="number">

Sample-2 : (Have tried this to solve issue in numeric keypad but doesnt work)

```
<input (keydown)="if(event.key=='.' || event.keyCode == 229 ||event.key===null ||event.key=='Unindentified'){event.preventDefaul();}" type="number">
```

Any help?

Comment: do you want to allow negative numbers tho?

Comment: I would suggest you to filter the value afterwards. Instead of preventing the event. Just handle the value afterwards. Because you still can copy a number with decimals and paste it into it.

Comment: i would block the paste operation using pipes.

Comment: it's a bit old but.. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460923/angular-2-restrict-input-field/54462816#54462816)

Comment: The above example  doesnt work on type='number', it works only on type='text'.. i want it to work on numeric keypad.

Comment: While not an angular solution, they're solving that in native javascript https://stackoverflow.com/a/65000594/9349240

Comment: Doesn't work for input type number